# Scraping and parsing citation info from Google Scholar search results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-scholar

I have a list of around 20000 article's titles and i want to **scrape** their citation count from google scholar. I am new to BeautifulSoup library. I have this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = ['Role for migratory wild birds in the global spread of avian 
 influenza H5N8','Uncoupling conformational states from activity in an 
 allosteric enzyme','Technological Analysis of the World’s Earliest 
 Shamanic Costume: A Multi-Scalar, Experimental Study of a Red Deer 
 Headdress from the Early Holocene Site of Star Carr, North Yorkshire, 
 UK','Oxidative potential of PM 2.5  during Atlanta rush hour: 
 Measurements of in-vehicle dithiothreitol (DTT) activity','Primary 
 Prevention of CVD','Growth and Deposition of Au Nanoclusters on Polymer- 
 wrapped Graphene and Their Oxygen Reduction Activity','Relations of 
 Preschoolers Visual-Motor and Object Manipulation Skills With Executive 
 Function and Social Behavior','We Know Who Likes Us, but Not Who Competes 
 Against Us']

url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + query + '&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF- 
       8&hl=en&btnG=Search'

content = requests.get(url).text
page = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
results = []
for entry in page.find_all("h3", attrs={"class": "gs_rt"}):
    results.append({"title": entry.a.text, "url": entry.a['href']})
```

but it returns only title and url. i don't know how to get the citation information from another tag. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop the list. You can use Session for efficiency. The below is for bs 4.7.1 which supports `:contains` pseudo class for finding the citation count. Looks like you can remove the `h3` type selector from the css selector and just use class before the `a` i.e. `.gs_rt a`. If you don't have 4.7.1. you can use `[title=Cite] + a` to select citation count instead.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

queries = ['Role for migratory wild birds in the global spread of avian influenza H5N8',
         'Uncoupling conformational states from activity in an allosteric enzyme',
         'Technological Analysis of the World’s Earliest Shamanic Costume: A Multi-Scalar, Experimental Study of a Red Deer Headdress from the Early Holocene Site of Star Carr, North Yorkshire, UK',
         'Oxidative potential of PM 2.5  during Atlanta rush hour: Measurements of in-vehicle dithiothreitol (DTT) activity',
         'Primary Prevention of CVD','Growth and Deposition of Au Nanoclusters on Polymer-wrapped Graphene and Their Oxygen Reduction Activity',
         'Relations of Preschoolers Visual-Motor and Object Manipulation Skills With Executive Function and Social Behavior',
         'We Know Who Likes Us, but Not Who Competes Against Us']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for query in queries:
        url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + query + '&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&btnG=Search'
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') # or 'html.parser'
        title = soup.select_one('h3.gs_rt a').text if soup.select_one('h3.gs_rt a') is not None else 'No title'
        link = soup.select_one('h3.gs_rt a')['href'] if title != 'No title' else 'No link'
        citations = soup.select_one('a:contains("Cited by")').text if soup.select_one('a:contains("Cited by")') is not None else 'No citation count'
        print(title, link, citations)
```

The alternative for <  4.7.1.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    for query in queries:
        url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + query + '&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&btnG=Search'
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') # or 'html.parser'
        title = soup.select_one('.gs_rt a')
        if title is None:
            title = 'No title'
            link = 'No link'
        else:  
            link = title['href']
            title = title.text
        citations = soup.select_one('[title=Cite] + a')
        if citations is None:
            citations = 'No citation count'
        else:
             citations = citations.text
        print(title, link, citations)
```

Bottom version re-written thanks to comments from @facelessuser. Top version left for comparison:

*It would probably be more efficient to not call select_one twice in single line if statement. While the pattern building is cached, the returned tag is not cached. I personally would set the variable to whatever is returned by select_one and then, only if the variable is None, change it to No link or No title etc. It isn't as compact, but it will be more efficient*

*[...]always check if if tag is None: and not just if tag:. With selectors, it isn't a big deal as they will only return tags, but if you ever do something like for x in tag.descendants: you get text nodes (strings) and tags, and an empty string will evaluate false even though it is a valid node. In that case, it is safest to to check for None*

Comment: That is because your version is less than 4.7.1. Use the bottom script or upgrade your bs4

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped :-)

Comment: It would probably be more efficient to not call `select_one` twice in single line if statement. While the pattern building is cached, the returned tag is not cached. I personally would set the variable to whatever is returned by `select_one` and then, only if the variable is None, change it to `No link` or  `No title` etc. It isn't as compact, but it will be more efficient.

Comment: @facelessuser Thanks. I really appreciate feedback to help me improve. I am still pretty new to python. Is the first variation I show here, https://pastebin.com/Ci15fWqw,  close to what you mean? I show a second variation with select.

Comment: Yeah, the pastebin is more inline with what I'm talking about. In general, I also always check if  `if tag is None:` and not just `if tag:`. With selectors, it isn't a big deal as they will only return tags, but if you ever do something like `for x in tag.descendants:` you get text nodes (strings) and tags, and an empty string will evaluate false even though it is a valid node.  In that case, it is safest to to check for None.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding all `<h3>` tags, I suggest you to search for the tags enclosing both `<h3>` and the citation (inside `<div class="gs_rs>"`), i.e. find all `<div class="gs_ri">` tags.

Then from these tags, you should be able to get all you need:

```
query = ['Role for migratory wild birds in the global spread of avian influenza H5N8','Uncoupling conformational states from activity in an allosteric enzyme','Technological Analysis of the World’s Earliest Shamanic Costume: A Multi-Scalar, Experimental Study of a Red Deer Headdress from the Early Holocene Site of Star Carr, North Yorkshire, UK','Oxidative potential of PM 2.5  during Atlanta rush hour: Measurements of in-vehicle dithiothreitol (DTT) activity','Primary Prevention of CVD','Growth and Deposition of Au Nanoclusters on Polymer- wrapped Graphene and Their Oxygen Reduction Activity','Relations of Preschoolers Visual-Motor and Object Manipulation Skills With Executive Function and Social Behavior','We Know Who Likes Us, but Not Who Competes Against Us']

url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + query + '&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&btnG=Search'

content = requests.get(url).text
page = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
results = []
for entry in page.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "gs_ri"}): #tag containing both h3 and citation
    results.append({"title": entry.h3.a.text, "url": entry.a['href'], "citation": entry.find("div", attrs={"class": "gs_rs"}).text})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using `user-agent` because default requests `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google might block your requests and you receive a different HTML with some sort of error that doesn't contain selectors you're trying to select. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

It also might be a good idea to [rotate `user-agents`](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/) while making requests.

Code and [full example that scrapes much more in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Scholar-pythonserpapi#bs4_results/get_organic.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

queries = ['Role for migratory wild birds in the global spread of avian influenza H5N8',
'Uncoupling conformational states from activity in an allosteric enzyme',
'Technological Analysis of the World’s Earliest Shamanic Costume: A Multi-Scalar, Experimental Study of a Red Deer Headdress from the Early Holocene Site of Star Carr, North Yorkshire, UK',
'Oxidative potential of PM 2.5  during Atlanta rush hour: Measurements of in-vehicle dithiothreitol (DTT) activity',
'Primary Prevention of CVD','Growth and Deposition of Au Nanoclusters on Polymer-wrapped Graphene and Their Oxygen Reduction Activity',
'Relations of Preschoolers Visual-Motor and Object Manipulation Skills With Executive Function and Social Behavior',
'We Know Who Likes Us, but Not Who Competes Against Us']

for query in queries:
  params = {
    "q": query,
    "hl": "en",
  }

  html = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/scholar', headers=headers, params=params, proxies=proxies).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

  # Container where all needed data is located
  for result in soup.select('.gs_ri'):
    title = result.select_one('.gs_rt').text
    title_link = result.select_one('.gs_rt a')['href']
    cited_by = result.select_one('#gs_res_ccl_mid .gs_nph+ a')['href']
    cited_by_count = result.select_one('#gs_res_ccl_mid .gs_nph+ a').text.split(' ')[2]

    print(f"{title}\n{title_link}\n{cited_by}\n{cited_by_count}\n")
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Scholar Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want, rather than figuring out why certain things don't work as they should.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

queries = ['Role for migratory wild birds in the global spread of avian influenza H5N8',
'Uncoupling conformational states from activity in an allosteric enzyme',
'Technological Analysis of the World’s Earliest Shamanic Costume: A Multi-Scalar, Experimental Study of a Red Deer Headdress from the Early Holocene Site of Star Carr, North Yorkshire, UK',
'Oxidative potential of PM 2.5  during Atlanta rush hour: Measurements of in-vehicle dithiothreitol (DTT) activity',
'Primary Prevention of CVD','Growth and Deposition of Au Nanoclusters on Polymer-wrapped Graphene and Their Oxygen Reduction Activity',
'Relations of Preschoolers Visual-Motor and Object Manipulation Skills With Executive Function and Social Behavior',
'We Know Who Likes Us, but Not Who Competes Against Us']

for query in queries:
  params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
    "engine": "google_scholar",
    "q": query,
  }

  search = GoogleSearch(params)
  results = search.get_dict()

  data = []

  for result in results['organic_results']:
    data.append({
      'title': result['title'],
      'link': result['link'],
      'publication_info': result['publication_info']['summary'],
      'snippet': result['snippet'],
      'cited_by': result['inline_links']['cited_by']['link'],
      'related_versions': result['inline_links']['related_pages_link'],
    })

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

P.S - I wrote a blog post about how to scrape pretty much everything on [Google Scholar](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-scholar-with-python-32oh) with visual representation.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.