# Problems in retrieving Google Scholar results with BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-scholar

I am continuing the analysis started in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672854/extract-academic-publication-information-from-ideas/60674889#60674889) of mine. I have obtained information about specific working paper publications in a data frame composed by four columns: year of publication, order of publication (the publication's order for each year, quite useless in this situation), title, and author. Therefore, I want to use this data frame to scrape Google Scholar and retrieve information about the number of citation. 
Because some paper's titles are a bit of generic, in some cases the first outcome of google scholar is not actually the one I am interested in. Therefore, to perform a more tailored research, in the creation of the link to perform the research I have included both the title and the author(s) of each paper. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220399/scraping-and-parsing-citation-info-from-google-scholar-search-results) thread in writing the code.

Note: because true names are needed to perform this scraping, I preferred to not create an example data frame. I have uploaded the .csv file on my GitHub instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from random import randint
from time import sleep

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicolacaravaggio/working_paper_roma3/master/rm3_working_paper_list.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines = False)

papers = [] 

for index, rows in df.iterrows():  
    list_paper = rows.title + ' ' + rows.author

    papers.append(list_paper)

title_list_gs = []
citations_list_gs = []

with requests.Session() as s:

    for paper in papers: 

            sleep(randint(1,3))

            url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + paper + '&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&btnG=Search'
            r = s.get(url)
            soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

            title_gs = soup.select_one('h3.gs_rt a').text if soup.select_one('h3.gs_rt a') is not None else 'No title'
            title_list_gs.append(title_gs)

            citations_gs = soup.select_one('a:contains("Cited by")').text if soup.select_one('a:contains("Cited by")') is not None else 'No citation count'
            citations_list_gs.append(citations_gs)

            print('Title:', title_gs, '; Citations:', citations_gs)
```

However, the result I get from this script is just a list of:

```
Title: No title ; Citations: No Citation count
```

I am not sure if the problem is in my clumsy script (probably) or in the fact that Google prevent me to scrape too much from Scholar. In fact, even the [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220399/scraping-and-parsing-citation-info-from-google-scholar-search-results) that I used as starting point in this thread, it not always return with the expected outcome. I hope someone could give me some suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It shows a captcha this is why it doesn't return any data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are triggering Scholars bot detection. From personal experience scraping Google Scholar, 45 seconds is enough to avoid CAPTCHA and bot detection. I have had a scraper running for >3 days without detection. If you do get flagged, waiting about 2 hours is enough to start again. [Here is an extract from my code.](https://pastebin.com/Tb5zitZb).

```
class ScholarScrape():
    def __init__(self):
        self.page = None
        self.last_url = None
        self.last_time = time.time()
        self.min_time_between_scrape = int(ConfigFile.instance().config.get('scholar','bot_avoidance_time'))
        self.header = {'User-Agent':ConfigFile.instance().config.get('scholar','user_agent')}
        self.session = requests.Session()
        pass

    def search(self, query=None, year_lo=None, year_hi=None, title_only=False, publication_string=None, author_string=None, include_citations=True, include_patents=True):
        url = self.get_url(query, year_lo, year_hi, title_only, publication_string, author_string, include_citations, include_patents)
        while True:
            wait_time = self.min_time_between_scrape - (time.time() - self.last_time)
            if wait_time > 0:
                logger.info("Delaying search by {} seconds to avoid bot detection.".format(wait_time))
                time.sleep(wait_time)
            self.last_time = time.time()
            logger.info("SCHOLARSCRAPE: " + url)
            self.page = BeautifulSoup(self.session.get(url, headers=self.header).text, 'html.parser')
            self.last_url = url

            if "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network" in str(self.page):
                raise BotDetectionException("Google has blocked this computer for a short time because it has detected this scraping script.")

            return

    def get_url(self, query=None, year_lo=None, year_hi=None, title_only=False, publication_string=None, author_string=None, include_citations=True, include_patents=True):
        base_url = "https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?"
        url = base_url + "as_q=" + urllib.parse.quote(query)

        if year_lo is not None and bool(re.match(r'.*([1-3][0-9]{3})', str(year_lo))):
            url += "&as_ylo=" + str(year_lo)

        if year_hi is not None and bool(re.match(r'.*([1-3][0-9]{3})', str(year_hi))):
            url += "&as_yhi=" + str(year_hi)

        if title_only:
            url += "&as_yhi=title"
        else:
            url += "&as_yhi=any"

        if publication_string is not None:
            url += "&as_publication=" + urllib.parse.quote('"' + str(publication_string) + '"')

        if author_string is not None:
            url += "&as_sauthors=" + urllib.parse.quote('"' + str(author_string) + '"')

        if include_citations:
            url += "&as_vis=0"
        else:
            url += "&as_vis=1"

        if include_patents:
            url += "&as_sdt=0"
        else:
            url += "&as_sdt=1"

        return url

    def get_results_count(self):
        e = self.page.findAll("div", {"class": "gs_ab_mdw"})
        try:
            item = e[1].text.strip()
        except IndexError as ex:
            if "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network" in str(self.page):
                raise BotDetectionException("Google has blocked this computer for a short time because it has detected this scraping script.")
            else:
                raise ex

        if self.has_numbers(item):
            return self.get_results_count_from_soup_string(item)
        for item in e:
            item = item.text.strip()
            if self.has_numbers(item):
                return self.get_results_count_from_soup_string(item)
        return 0

    @staticmethod
    def get_results_count_from_soup_string(element):
        if "About" in element:
            num = element.split(" ")[1].strip().replace(",","")
        else:
            num = element.split(" ")[0].strip().replace(",","")
        return num

    @staticmethod
    def has_numbers(input_string):
        return any(char.isdigit() for char in input_string)


class BotDetectionException(Exception):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = ScholarScrape()
    s.search(**{
        "query":"\"policy shaping\"",
        # "publication_string":"JMLR",
        "author_string": "gilboa",
        "year_lo": "1995",
        "year_hi": "2005",

    })
    x = s.get_results_count()
    print(x)
```

[This question might have more information to help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60535351/web-scraping-google-search-results/60536180#60536180)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use a third party solution like SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial. We handle proxies, solve captchas, and parse all rich structured data for you.

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "secret_api_key",
  "engine": "google_scholar",
  "q": "Francesco Crespi",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
{
  "position": 1,
  "title": "Demand and innovation in productivity growth",
  "result_id": "6vfKIRtQWRQJ",
  "link": "https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02692170802407429",
  "snippet": "The labour productivity impact of demand and innovation is investigated in this paper combining insights from the Kaldorian and Schumpeterian traditions. After a review of studies in such traditions, a general model is proposed for explaining productivity growth in …",
  "publication_info": {
    "summary": "F Crespi, M Pianta - International Review of Applied Economics, 2008 - Taylor & Francis",
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "F Crespi",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=gKdC5-0AAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra",
        "serpapi_scholar_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?author_id=gKdC5-0AAAAJ&engine=google_scholar_author&hl=en",
        "author_id": "gKdC5-0AAAAJ"
      },
      {
        "name": "M Pianta",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=knrxY9EAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra",
        "serpapi_scholar_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?author_id=knrxY9EAAAAJ&engine=google_scholar_author&hl=en",
        "author_id": "knrxY9EAAAAJ"
      }
    ]
  },
  "inline_links": {
    "serpapi_cite_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_cite&q=6vfKIRtQWRQJ",
    "cited_by": {
      "total": 88,
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=1466291231147096042&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en",
      "cites_id": "1466291231147096042",
      "serpapi_scholar_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?as_sdt=2005&cites=1466291231147096042&engine=google_scholar&hl=en"
    },
    "related_pages_link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=related:6vfKIRtQWRQJ:scholar.google.com/&scioq=Francesco+Crespi&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5",
    "versions": {
      "total": 7,
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1466291231147096042&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5",
      "cluster_id": "1466291231147096042",
      "serpapi_scholar_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?as_sdt=0%2C5&cluster=1466291231147096042&engine=google_scholar&hl=en"
    }
  }
},
...
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*